# My UV sphere wont curve the meshes around the bedpost like this tutorial I'm following

Tags: modeling, mesh

I'm pretty new so if there are any blender gods, please hear me out. I'm following this online video (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yCHT23A6aJA&t=389s) on 3d modeling a small room and at 6:32 (when he modeled a UV sphere on top of the bed post) I noticed that when he tabbed back to object mode, the meshes sort of blended together towards the sphere.

[image: see how they curve inward]

Whereas when I tried it for myself, it did not have the same effect.
[image: my results]

If any of you could explain why this is so, I would highly appreciate it.

Comment: i'm not sure it blends, it's just that the sphere is a bit lower on the video

Comment: @moonboots I think that the tutor did join the edge loop of the sphere and post... Otherwise, how would the bevel effect the sphere and post as if it were the same object if it wasn't connected through any edges in edit mode?

Comment: slightly different geometry. his post has a slight collar with his sphere embedded a bit deeper into the post.

Comment: @moonboots you're right, I checked the video

Comment: @HarryMcKenzie you're right too, and the tutor's post seems to be a bit more bevelled, even though the value is higher in the OP's screenshot

Comment: so am i right (from what i infer from your comments) in saying that it's basically because of the bevel values, and not because of some other thing in his model?